# Display a list of items based on value in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

How do I display the items based on 'delivered' status in the database? I have my get request set up and working. I'm just not sure how to only display the ones that have the status of delivered in react.

Thanks for any help :)

My mongoDB database

```
const Package = new mongoose.Schema({
  packageID =  {type: String},
  packageStatus = {type: String, enum: [packed, delivered, received], default: 'packed' },
})
```

Comment: Are you able to send a `GET` request to server and get all data as `JSON`?

Comment: Are you looking for the mongo query for this?

Comment: @ShivamJha yes I can display all items in Package Schema on react but I only want to display those with a packageStatus of 'delivered'. How do I code that in react or is it something to do with the Api?

Comment: @TusharShahi I use a GET request to display all the data but I just want to display those with the status of  'delivered'. Do I mention this in the mongo query or react page?

Comment: @TusharShahi This is my mongo query

const listPackage = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const package = await package.find()
        return res.send(package)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400)
        return res.send("Database query failed")
    }
}

Comment: You can mention it in your query. That way you have fewer data items to process.

Comment: @TusharShahi Yes it works! Thank you so much :) How about if I want to display text on react page based on the packageStatus, how do I mention it in react? For example, if packageStatus is "delivered", I would want my page in react to display "Package has been delivered" but if the status is "packed", I would want to text to display "Package has been packed. Order will be delivered soon".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
//The mongo query
db.package.find( { "packageStatus ": "delivered" } )

//In your case: 
const listPackage = async (req, res) => 
{ 
try 
{ const packages = await package.find({ "packageStatus ": "delivered" }); 
return res.send(packages); 
} 
catch (err) 
{ res.status(400) return res.send("Database query failed") } 
}
```